# I don't have any options for UK tier 2 general shortage work visa subtype

Tags: visas, schengen-visas, work

I tried to apply for a tier 2 general shortage work visa to the UK. I tried their site and can't select subtype. I tried the new site but can't find a tier 2 general shortage work visa. Anyone know what I can do?
[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP needs to contact the Support Team for the site.